# proving an inequality for combinatorial sum

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics

The following inequality comes from the literature:  *N. Alon, Y. Caro,  On the number of subgraphs of prescribed type of planar graphs with a given number of vertices //North-Holland Mathematics Studies. North-Holland, 1984, 87: 25-36.* This inequality plays a pivotal role in proving an upper bound on the number of copies of
$K_{1,k}$ in planar graphs.

> If $\bar{y}=\left(y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n\right)$ and $\bar{z}=\left(z_1, \ldots, z_n\right)$ are **nondecreasing sequences** of **positive integers**, and if there exist $i$ and $j, 1 \leqslant i<j \leqslant n$, such that $z_i=y_i-1$, $z_i=y_i+1$ and $z_l=y_l$, for all $l \neq i, j$, then we say that $\bar{z}$ is obtained from $\bar{y}$ by a *simple improvement.* It is easily checked that in this case $$ \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\begin{array}{l} y_i \\ k \end{array}\right) \leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\begin{array}{l} z_i \\ k \end{array}\right), \text { for all } k \geqslant 2, $$ and the inequality is **strict iff** $y_j \geqslant k-1$.

The author states that it is easily verifiable, but I haven't yet conceived a rigorous proof for this inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We wish to prove that $\sum{z_i\choose k}-\sum{y_i\choose k}\ge0$; by the conditions given this amounts to showing that
$${y_j+1\choose k}-{y_j\choose k}+{y_i-1\choose k}-{y_i\choose k}\ge0.$$
Now
\begin{align*}
{y_j+1\choose k}-{y_j\choose k}
&={(y_j+1)\dots(y_j-k+2)\over k!}-{y_j\dots(y_j-k+1)\over k!}\\
&={y_j\dots(y_j-k+2)\over k!}(y_j+1-(y_j-k+1))\\
&={y_j\dots(y_j-k+2)\over(k-1)!};
\end{align*}
similarly we have
$${y_i-1\choose k}-{y_i\choose k}
=-{(y_i-1)\dots(y_i-k+1)\over(k-1)!}.$$
Thus we are left to prove that
$$y_j\dots(y_j-k+2)\ge(y_i-1)\dots(y_i-k+1),$$
which follows from the fact that $y_j\ge y_i$.

Comment: Sorry. I still don't understand why proving ${y_j+1\choose k}-{y_j\choose k}+{y_i-1\choose k}-{y_i\choose k}\ge0$ is sufficient.

Comment: I see. It is my mistake. I mistakenly interpreted all $l \neq i,j$ with $y_l=z_l$ as the existence of $l$ where $l \neq i,j$ with $y_l=z_l$.